# Recording the 17 year cicadas in Virginia

Tags: field-recording, insects

Totally random, does anyone plan to record the 17 year cicadas in Virginia/West Virginia this summer?

http://www.cicadamania.com/cicadas/category/brood-i/

Answer (score 1):

Having just looked this up, I would definitely like to but the journey from London is a bit too long for me!

I just listened to the stuff here:

http://www.bbc.co.uk/nature/life/Magicicada

"So both both the 13 and 17 year cicadas have cycles that are prime numbers, this makes it difficult for predators to time their own population increases to match what the cicadas are up to"

That's some pretty amazing evolution.

Be nice to hear some recordings if you get any.

Answer (score 1):

Since I left the state, I nominate @Shaun Farley. ;^P